# How to get Japanese Kanji characters as an input mode?

Tags: gnome, input-method, japanese, kanji

I am learning Japanese and I have found that after installing `Japanese (Anthy)` through the `gnome-control-center` that I have several input modes available to type with now under that, `Hiragana`, `Katakana`, `Halfwidth Katakana`, `Latin`, and `Wide Latin`. However, there is no `Kanji`. I could probably install it by installing the Chinese input source, but I may not be able to find the correct characters because of difference in meaning and pronunciation so it would be preferable if I could get the Japanese one (so that I can type `watashi` instead of `I` to get `私` - `I` would be for the Chinese one, and `watashi` for the Japanese one).

So how does one install Kanji? And can one use it as an input mode? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

**Just to clarify:** I want Kanji and not Kana (the name for individual Hiragana and Katakana characters) as I've already found that.

Comment: Install `ibus-kkc`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: Ok, I have installed that now, so how do I get access to Kanji? Do I need to reboot or something as well?

Comment: At least relogin.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: Ok, well, after a restart I can't find Kanji, where exactly would it be and how would I access it?

Comment: Well, on Unity it appears in Text Entry. I'm not sure, but there might be some stupid "whitelist" or "blacklist" in Ubuntu GNOME which hides certain input sources by default. If so, it needs to be modified, but I can't tell how.

Comment: In [this bug report (comment 1)](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=880007) you find a terminal command which might help.

Comment: I installed `ibus-kkc` on my Ubuntu GNOME (Xenial), and after a relogin, "Japanese (Kana Kanji)" showed up among the Japanese input sources in Region & Language, without a need to enable that "show-all-sources" option.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: Ah! Thanks! Didn't see it there (though it would be much more useful as an input mode of `Japanese (Anthy)`)! Please post an answer on this so I can accept it.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: Wait, it says Kana Kanji, this is Kanji and not Kana right?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. ;) As regards an answer, please post it (and accept it) yourself if the `ibus-kkc` package is what you want.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: No, I think that's actually Kana which is not what I want...

Comment: Unlike Anthy it includes a "direct input" mode. (So does `ibus-mozc`, btw.)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: Well, that just seems to type in English unless I've got the wrong idea about this feature?

Comment: Then I don't know. I just saw "Kanji" in the name of the input source.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson: Ah, well maybe I'll have to make a Kanji input source then!

Comment: Just look into how Anthy (or IMEs in general) works. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Anthy input method that you are using is able to input kanji.

After you type a word (or even a long phrase) in kana, just press the <kbd>Space bar</kbd> in order to bring up the kanji conversion.

Anthy will provide several options based on frequency of use in Japanese, words and phrases commonly used together, and on your local frequency of use.